# I want a code to call servlet from java code. My code is given below. Servlet not getting called,

Tags: java, servlets

```
package test;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://localhost:8081/Projectt/ServletTest");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        out.writeObject("test");
        out.flush();
        System.out.println("------------");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Here's my servlet code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
@WebServlet("/ServletTest")
public class ServletTest extends HttpServlet {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     public ServletTest() {
         super();
     }
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    doPost(request,response);
}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());
    try {
        System.out.println("In get : " + (String) in.readObject());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("End of servlet");
}
}
```

I want to call servlet from java code. Above is my code.
Port is 8081. URL given gets fired from the browser but not from my code.
Only the println statement gets executed from the Test class and not from the TestServlet

Comment: Have you tried adding a breakpoint to the `doPost` method to see if it gets hit?  Do the Tomcat logs reveal any sort of errors happening?

Comment: Yes. I tried with breakpoints but it's not getting executed. Not any error in tomcat log file too.

Comment: What is the name of your WAR file?

Comment: War file name "Projectt"

Comment: It really has 2 T's at the end?

Comment: Yes it is..@TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Yo, why are you even using that outdated way to make connections like that? There are libraries (`retrofit`) that will do a lot of this work for you. I suggest looking into them if you are trying to get something done.

Comment: Then shouldn't your connection URL be `http://localhost:8081/Projectt/ServletTest` ?

Comment: But your code has `"http://localhost:8081/Project/ServletTest"` without the double 't'. And why do you *have* a double 't'? Don't use mis-spellings.

Comment: It still have same problem

Comment: Have you considered reading my answer? and implementing it? Or are you only reading the comments here?

Comment: Will have a look @SamOrozco Thanks...

Comment: Yes i did it @EJP It still have same problem.

Comment: So what *was* the response code? This is like getting blood from a stone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing happens until you do some input, i.e. acquire the `HttpURLConnection`'s input stream or get the response code. You need to at least call [`getResponseCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode--).

Comment: Respose code is 200. But nothing gets printed from servlet code

Comment: But you said above it didn't work when you tried it. What are we to understand  from this? You didn't implement it? The response code wasn't 200 until you fixed the URL? For this question to have any future value here you need to clearly identify what the solution was, and the relevance of your comments that contradict this answer. Or delete them.